# each portion of image having (or with) different id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image with id `myimage`. It has a width of `300px` and height `100px`. each 100px wide portion has a unique color, like below

```
------------------------
| red  | green | blue  |
------------------------
```

Is it possible to use each portion (having width & height `100px`) with different id so that the image can be used as a button with different functions to each portion??

Answer only if it is possible and comment for others.

thanks in advance...`:)`
[image]

Comment: You can do it easily using css.use this image as background for button and change the x and y positioning like css sprite

Comment: In the good ol' days there were image maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image as a background image and give the parent div `position:relative` property. Then use nested divs with `position:absolute` each 100px apart from one another.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>

#wrap{
    background:transparent url(...) no-repeat 0 0;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.first, .second, .third{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.first{
    left:0;
}
.second{
    left:100px;
}
.third{
    left:200px;
}
```

Now using JQuery you can reference each part individually.

```
$('.first').click(function(){ // this is the first part
 alert('first clicked')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/PrMzr/

Comment: i got it.. But is there any way that i can change the image portion down to the div portion when i hover to the specific div??

Comment: i mean, is there any way i can change class or change background image position or margin when i hover to specific div??

Comment: The image is one piece, you can't move parts of it individually. if you want to have some type of a hover effect you can either show a background color with low opacity or you can add a border.

Comment: ... or just split it into three separate images.

Comment: check the image i added. I think i can make something by setting margin (x and y position) of background image..